# Прописная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Музей истории полиции и милиции. Слово музей с прописной или строчной буквы?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Музей истории милиции Культурного центра ГУВД Санкт-Петербурга и Ленинградской области (Музей милиции)

Центральный музей МВД России

Музей истории московской полиции

Музей истории самарской милиции

директор музея истории полиции и милиции Вачского района Нижегородской области

Comment: Спасибо. Меня как раз интересовал музей Вачского района.

Answer (score 0):

Если "музей" выступает в качестве наименования, то нужна прописная буква. Если это имя нарицательное, тогда пишется строчная.

Дополнение

> В официальных составных названиях органов власти, учреждений, организаций, научных, учебных и ***зрелищных заведений,*** обществ, политических партий и объединений ***с прописной буквы пишется первое слово и входящие в состав названия имена собственные, а также первое слово включаемых в них названий других учреждений и организаций, напр.:***

***Государственная Третьяковская галерея,*** Государственный академический Большой театр, Московский Художественный академический театр, Государственный Русский музей (и неофициальные их названия: ***Третьяковская галерея, Большой театр, Художественный театр, Русский музей***); ***Музей искусств народов Востока***, Государственная публичная историческая библиотека, Центральный дом художника, Театральное училище им. М. С. Щепкина.

***Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.***

Comment: Если "музей" - первое слово в названии музея, то пишется с прописной: директор Музея истории полиции и милиции Вачского района Нижегородской области.

Comment: Но ведь это не имя собственное

Comment: Корректно: директор музея истории полиции и милиции Вачского района Нижегородской области. Здесь ''музей'' имя нарицательное, а не собственное.

Answer (score 0):

Музей истории полиции и милиции Вачского района Нижегородской области. Как узнать Музей - это первое слово имени собственного (то есть официального названия) или имя нарицательное? Если нет возможности заглянуть в документы или в справочник (если таковой есть).